# custom css for google maps api v3 'directions-panel'

Tags: css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Been searching for the last hour or so and cannot find anything regarding custom css for the directions panel output for Google Maps v3.  I am trying to customize the css for the text-directions as shown at [Google Doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-panel).

I took at look at the css generated on my map and it is using various ids and classes starting with 'adp', but the few places I did find in my searching had no reference to this.

Is there any 'standard' css or method to customize it?  I am afraid to modify these 'adp' entries for fear that it will change at any time or that is possibly different naming for different people/locations.

Any information on this would be great!

Comment: im afraid there isn't any standard way. i needed to do the same thing and had to do it by digging up class names from devtools.

Comment: ugh... so are you comfortable with the naming not changing on you?  I haven't used maps in the past so I don't know how they typical handle changes/new versions when they are available.  That is really the only thing I am worried about.

Comment: i can tell you that they haven't changed the class names in the last 7 months but i'm not aware of any change that might have happened before. i think google maps is a mature library and besides code even the html probably will always be the same as long as you keep using the same api version.

Comment: I guess I am going to go ahead and use these 'adp' names then.  I guess if something changes I will hear something from visitors or see it myself.  Thanks for the input!